# OpenOffice Automation Issue when Launched from Separate Thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, com, activex

I have a C++ application that sometimes needs to export information to a spreadsheet. It is designed to do so using COM and ActiveX integration with Microsoft Excel and OpenOffice Calc.

I noticed with one of the newer versions of OpenOffice that my program would timeout and fail any time I tried doing the export.

I did quite a bit of research before figuring out that the failure required the following two events:

1.) Creation of a simple UI window with a custom procedure (even if that procedure did not do anything more than pass everything on to the default procedure)

2.) Creation of a separate thread in which the code to launch OpenOffice (via COM and ActiveX) is executed

I should note that any given time, there is only ONE thread doing OpenOffice integration. It just happens to be a different thread from the one handling the UI.

I also noticed some other oddities.

If the window class does NOT involve a custom procedure, no error occurs. However, if ANY custom procedure is involved it does occur. Even if the custom window procedure does absolutely nothing but pass all messages to the default window procedure, the error occurs.

If no UI window is made, the code in the separate thread executes flawlessly.

If the integration code is launched from the same thread as the UI, no error occurs. If the integration is first carried out within the same thread as the UI, subsequent creation and execution of a separate thread runs without error.

And this is the weirdest observation: I'm using Visual Studio 2005 for debugging. If I set a breakpoint just prior to the invocation of "loadComponentFromURL", the hang will NOT occur. However, if I do NOT set a break point, when the hang occurs I can break execution and I'll find that the call stack indicates that it is stuck somewhere within the process of RPC invocation awaiting a return from WaitForMultipleObjectsEx(...).

Below is a complete code example. If you compile and run this on a machine with the newest version of OpenOffice, it will hang. Within the WinMain(...) function, there is a call to TestOOCalc that is commented out. If you uncomment it, you'll find the program now launches OpenOffice Calc perfectly.

Given that there are NOT multiple threads attempting to access OpenOffice at the same time, this doesn't seem like it should be a threading issue at all.

I can't find anything anywhere about this phenomenon or what the root cause is. I really don't want to resort to putting all of the work in the same thread as the UI as this would make the UI unresponsive during lengthy operations.

Thoughts? Ideas?

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <atlbase.h>
#include <process.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}

BOOL MakeUIWindow(HINSTANCE hInstance)
{
    // Class definition for Main Window
    WNDCLASS wndclass;
    ZeroMemory(&wndclass, sizeof(wndclass));

    wndclass.style            = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wndclass.lpfnWndProc      = WndProc;
    wndclass.hInstance        = hInstance;
    wndclass.lpszClassName    = TEXT("Problem Window Class");

    // Register the Main Window class
    if (!RegisterClass(&wndclass))
        return FALSE;

    HWND hwnd = CreateWindowEx(0, TEXT("Problem Window Class"), 
                                        TEXT("Problem"), WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
                                       10, 10, 500, 500, 
                                        NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

    ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_NORMAL);

    return TRUE;
}

BOOL ActiveX_MethodCall(CComPtr<IDispatch> &rcpPropInterface, const WCHAR *wszMethod, const UINT uiArgs, VARIANTARG *pArgs, CComPtr<IDispatch> &rcpResult)
{
    DISPID dispid;
    HRESULT hr = rcpPropInterface.GetIDOfName(wszMethod, &dispid);
    if (FAILED(hr))
        return FALSE;

    DISPPARAMS dp;
    EXCEPINFO ei;
    VARIANT varReturn;
    ZeroMemory(&varReturn, sizeof(varReturn));
    ZeroMemory(&dp, sizeof(dp));
    ZeroMemory(&ei, sizeof(ei));

    varReturn.vt = VT_EMPTY;

    dp.cArgs = uiArgs;
    dp.rgvarg = pArgs;

    hr = rcpPropInterface->Invoke(dispid, IID_NULL, NULL, DISPATCH_METHOD, &dp, &varReturn, NULL, NULL);

    if (FAILED(hr))
        return FALSE;

    rcpResult.Attach(varReturn.pdispVal);
    return TRUE;
}

// Performs an initialization of OpenOffice
BOOL TestOOCalc()
{
    if (FAILED(CoInitialize(NULL)))
        return FALSE;

    // Get class IDs for the ActiveX object specified
    CLSID clsid;
    if (FAILED(CLSIDFromProgID(L"com.sun.star.ServiceManager", &clsid)))
        return FALSE;

    CComPtr<IDispatch> cpSvcMgr;
    if (FAILED(cpSvcMgr.CoCreateInstance(clsid, NULL, CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER)))
        return FALSE;

    CComPtr<IDispatch> cpDesktop;
    { // context change for local variants
        VARIANTARG varArg;
        ZeroMemory(&varArg, sizeof(varArg));

        varArg.scode = DISP_E_PARAMNOTFOUND;
        varArg.vt = VT_BSTR;
        varArg.bstrVal = SysAllocString(L"com.sun.star.frame.Desktop");

        if (!ActiveX_MethodCall(cpSvcMgr, L"createInstance", 1, &varArg, cpDesktop))
        {
            VariantClear(&varArg);
            return FALSE;
        }

        VariantClear(&varArg);
    }

    // Call Desktop.loadComponentFromURL Method
    CComPtr<IDispatch> cpWorkbook;
    { // context change for local variants
        VARIANTARG pvarArgs[4];
        ZeroMemory(&pvarArgs, sizeof(pvarArgs));

        pvarArgs[3].scode = DISP_E_PARAMNOTFOUND;
        pvarArgs[3].vt = VT_BSTR;
        pvarArgs[3].bstrVal = SysAllocString(L"private:factory/scalc");

        pvarArgs[2].scode = DISP_E_PARAMNOTFOUND;
        pvarArgs[2].vt = VT_BSTR;
        pvarArgs[2].bstrVal = SysAllocString(L"_blank");

        pvarArgs[1].scode = DISP_E_PARAMNOTFOUND;
        pvarArgs[1].vt = VT_I4;
        pvarArgs[1].lVal = 0;

        SAFEARRAYBOUND saBound;
        saBound.lLbound = 0;
        saBound.cElements = 0;
        SAFEARRAY *psaArgs = SafeArrayCreate(VT_VARIANT, 1, &saBound);
        pvarArgs[0].scode = DISP_E_PARAMNOTFOUND;
        pvarArgs[0].vt = VT_ARRAY | VT_VARIANT;
        pvarArgs[0].parray = psaArgs;

        if (!ActiveX_MethodCall(cpDesktop, L"loadComponentFromURL", 4, pvarArgs, cpWorkbook))
        {
            SafeArrayDestroy(psaArgs);
            VariantClear(&pvarArgs[3]);
            VariantClear(&pvarArgs[2]);
            VariantClear(&pvarArgs[1]);
            VariantClear(&pvarArgs[0]);

            return FALSE;
        }

        SafeArrayDestroy(psaArgs);
        VariantClear(&pvarArgs[3]);
        VariantClear(&pvarArgs[2]);
        VariantClear(&pvarArgs[1]);
        VariantClear(&pvarArgs[0]);
    }

    return TRUE;
}

unsigned int __stdcall thrTestOOCalc(void *vShare)
{
    TestOOCalc();
    return 0;
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, PSTR szCmdLine, int iCmdShow)
{
    if (!MakeUIWindow(hInstance))
        return 0;

    //TestOOCalc();

    HANDLE hThread = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(NULL, 0, thrTestOOCalc, NULL, 0, NULL);
    WaitForSingleObject(hThread, INFINITE);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It has been a long time since a worked in a daily basis with COM, but to me this looks like the classic failure of pumping messages in an APARTMENT thread.

Check the following:

1. Are OpenOffice component declared as **apartment threaded** ?
2. If not, try to initialize your thread in MTA using [CoInitializeEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms695279%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).
3. If OO components **are** declared as apartment thread, you'll need to pump messages on your newly created thread.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you Vaugaus for the info. The documentation for OpenOffice automation is very weak, but I think it **is** apartment threaded. However, I'm not sure how or where to establish a message loop because my thread is never waiting for anything whenever the call stack is empty. On the contrary, the hang occurs whenever my thread invokes "loadComponentFromURL" which is part of the OO launch. The hangup occurs deep within the call stack where it forever awaits a return from WaitForMultipleObjectsEx(...).

Comment: COM docs state that the only case you'd not need a message pump for an apartment thread is if you only call simple methods (that does no callback, etc). I can imagine a scenario like this: You call into the OO component which decides to spawn a new thread for whatever reason and call a method (on itself or on another component, AFAIK, it doesn't matter); at this point you do require a message pump (since OO is crossing threads from an apartment component). Unfortunately I don't know exactly where to introduce the message pump either.

Comment: I found the issue. The problem was that the main UI thread was temporarily awaiting the signal for completion of the processing thread and was not cycling through it's message loop. By devising a messaging scheme and allowing the UI thread to resume it's message pump, the problem went away. So apparently the COM object was awaiting the result of some message it had posted on the UI thread. THANK YOU for getting me on the right track to figuring this out.

Comment: Great! I am happy I helped somehow :)